# I'm using Jquery to target the "src" attribute of my logo and

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quick question. I'm using jquery to target the "src" attribute of the logo on my website. So when the navbar shrinks (on scroll) the logo changes to a lighter version of the same image.

This worked PERFECTLY when I was making the site locally in HTML. It even worked perfectly when I uploaded the HTML to my web-host. However as I've started to move my site into a Wordpress theme, there is about a second delay in the image switch over. I was wondering If someone could take a look at my site and tell me what the problem might be? - Like I said, it was working perfectly locally and uploaded as plain HTML. Do I need to somehow preload the second image in jquery?

My URL is: http://iwebyou.com.au - Scroll down and notice when the navbar shrinks, there is a delay in the logo switching over. Also please ignore the rest of my website, its unfinished and everything else is a complete mess right now haha..

Cheers

Comment: It looks like you have an image downloading every time the user scrolls with their mouse. Are you sure you're not changing the `src` attribute on mouse scroll instead of page load?

Comment: Please post your relevant code here, [without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Exactly as @Adosi said, you are loading the image each time it's changed. Instead, you should have both images in the html and use JS/CSS to toggle the `opacity` of each image.

Comment: For future reference, you can look at the network tab in your browsers devtools to see what's happening.  Like the others mentioned, it's clear you're generating a fresh request to fetch the images every time you change the img src.

Comment: The reason is because now, inside of WordPress, your site is loading around 1meg of html, css, and javascript before your script can even load.  This takes time, so there is a delay before your script is able to execute....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to help further, but IMO the best solution would be to set the logo as a background-image via CSS classes and then change the css class with javascript when needed, rather then modifying an image src attribute.

```
<div class="logo logo-dark">Company Name for SEO</div>
```

and

```
<div class="logo logo-light">Company Name for SEO</div>
```

css:

```
.logo-dark {
  background-image: #fff url('path to dark logo') no-repeat center center;
}

.logo-light {
  background-image: #fff url('path to light logo') no-repeat center center;
}
.logo {
  // common logo styles
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to write this, I really appreciate it. I'm still learning so I'm sorry if this comes across as amateurish. - So I've given the "logo-dark" class a width of 180px and a height of 82px. The problem now I'm facing is that the logo image is massive so I'm having trouble scaling it down to fit inside the div as a background-image.

Comment: use `background-size` in css to handle that.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I think I've got it working. One thing. How can I remove the text inside the div? Do I just wrap it in a <span> and display:none ?

Comment: That's what I usually do, yep. `.logo span { display:none;}`.

Comment: Just moved it over to Wordpress and its working perfectly! Thank you mate I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `opacity` and `transition`:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
  if(window.scrollY > 50) {
    nav.classList.add('dark');
  }else {
    nav.classList.remove('dark');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.light {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.nav.dark {
  background: black;
}
.nav.dark .dark {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav.dark .light {
  opacity: 1;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="nav">
    <img src="https://www.iwebyou.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-I-Web-YouDark-2.png" class="dark" />
    <img src="https://www.iwebyou.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/I-Web-YouLight-2.png" class="light" />
  </div>
</div>
```